# Am I using Flutter Preview 1

Tags: dart, flutter

According to Google, Flutter Preview release 1 is available:

[Preview Release 1 post on medium](https://medium.com/flutter-io/flutter-release-preview-1-943a9b6ee65a?linkId=53249457)

I startete a project using **BETA 0.5.1**.

If I upgrade flutter from within Android Studio, it stays at release 0.5.1:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.5.1, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G65, locale de-DE)
```

- Is 0.5.1 actually Flutter Preview 1?
- Should I upgrade my project? How and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the latest version in *your **channel***, you can always run `flutter upgrade`.
If you want to switch to a more recent (and more unstable) channel, you can run `flutter channel dev` or `flutter channel master`.

Running `flutter channel` will show you all available channels:

- `beta`
- `dev`
- `master`

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a 1.0.0-pre release, then no. There are none.

The current flutter version out of 25 august is 0.7.1-pre.26 on master channel

You can run `flutter upgrade` to move to higher versions.
You can also use `flutter channel master` to switch on master branch